# Is there an alternative characterisation of vector bundles with vanishing characteristic classes?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, vector-bundles

This question came up yesterday during our index theory seminar.

Let $M$ be a 1-connected smooth manifold and let $E \to M$ be a finite-rank complex vector bundle over $M$.  If all the Chern classes of $E$ vanish, what else can one say about $E$?  In other words, is there an alternative characterisation of such $E$?

(For a similar question in the case of $M$ having nontrivial fundamental group, see [this previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35194/complex-vector-bundles-with-trivial-chern-classes-on-k-tori).)

Comment: A somewhat tautological but perhaps useful answer: A vector bundle given by $M \to BU$ has trivial Chern classes precisely when it lifts to the homotopy fibre of $BU \to \prod_n K(Z,2n)$ given by the Chern classes.

Comment: In the holomorphic world the general answer is "not much" without some kind of stability condition (e.g., take direct sums of line bundles.) But if your $E$ is stable, with respect to some polarization (I'm assuming $M$ projective also), then, since $M$ is $1$-connected, it will be trivial (Donaldson-Uhlenbeck, IIRC). (But maybe this is orthogonal to your real question, sorry.)

Comment: What do you mean by "take direct sums of line bundles"?
It should be an example of what?

Comment: The map in Torstens comment is $6$-connected ($\pi_*$-iso in degrees $\leq 5$, epi in degree $6$). Therefore the homotopy fibre is $5$-connected. That means that for manifolds of dimension $\leq 5$, such a vector bundle will be trivial.

Comment: Correction: $c_n$ on $S^{2n}$ has to be divisible by $(n-1)!$ (Bott). So the map isn't surjective on $\pi_6$. But it is still $5$-connected, and bundles with zero Chern classes are trivial in dimensions $\leq 4$.

Comment: Unless I misremember, the map $c_1\colon BU \to K(Z,2n)$ is given by multiplication by $(n-1)!$ on $\pi_{2n}$. That gives the homotopy groups of the homotopy fibre; $\mathbb Z/(n-1)!$ in degree $2n-1$ and zero in even degrees. Also I think that $c_n$ is a map of infinite loop spaces so that the fibre gives rise to a cohomology theory.

Comment: @Torsten: the computation of the homotopy fibres is correct. The second statement is wrong; c_n has no chance to be an infinite loop map, since $c_n(V \oplus W) \neq c_n (V) + c_n (W)$ in general. The maps that have a chance to be infinite loop maps are the components $s_n$ of the integral Chern character. They are not infinite loop maps, but certain multiples $m(n)s_n$, where $m(n) $ is a number that was computed explicitly by Adams.

Comment: The real Chern character is an infinite loop indeed, and the fibre is what is called $\Omega K(R/Z)$, and the role that it plays is that is the home of the invariants of flat vector bundles.

Comment: @Johannes: That was silly of me, I should have been able to realise that $c_i$ is not even an H-map. Thanks for putting me straight.

Comment: Let me try to redeem myself by pointing to a paper by Boyer et al (Algebraic cycles and infinite loop spaces, Invent. Math. 113) where they show that there is an infinite loop space structure on $\prod_nK/Z,2n)$ making $BU \to \prod_nK/Z,2n)$ an infinite loop space map so that in particular its homotopy fibre gives a cohomology theory (or better yet the homotopy fibre of the map from connective K-theory).

Answer (score 20):

Since no one has mentioned it yet, let me point out one possibly interesting observation.  If the base manifold $M$ is compact and has no torsion in its integral cohomology, then a vector bundle $E$ with vanishing Chern classes is stably trivial.  This was pointed out to me by Robert Lipshitz.  The reason is as follows: from looking at the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence, one can see that there can't be any torsion in the complex K-theory of $M$.  Looking at the Chern character, one concludes that $[E]$ must be trivial in $\widetilde{K}^0(M)$, i.e. $E$ is stably trivial.

Comment: By the way, I've been told (and it fits with the evidence) that Bott was always very interested in determining whether the (co)homology of various spaces was torsion-free.  I never really knew why that was such an interesting thing to prove, but the statement above strikes me as one very nice consequence of torsion-free-ness.

Comment: Would you mind saying a few more words about how you deduce that $K(M)$ is torsion-free? I can see that the torsion-free condition on cohomology implies that all the terms on the $E_2$ page of the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence are free abelian groups of finite rank, but I guess I don't know enough about the differentials. A priori, there could be some non-trivial differential $d^r : E^{p,q}_r \to E^{p+r,q-r+1}_r$ with $r$ odd whose image has finite index in $\operatorname{ker}(d^r : E^{p+r,q-r+1}_r \to E^{p+2r,q-2r+2}_r)$.

Comment: Basically the point is that we know a priori that ranks of $K^0 (M)$ and $K^1 (M)$ equal the total ranks of the even and odd degree cohomology groups (respectively), and these total ranks also agree with the total rank of the $E^2$ terms on the relevant anti-diagonals. A non-trivial differential anywhere in the spectral sequence would decrease the total rank on one of these lines, hence would decrease the total rank of $K^*(M)$. Kristen Hendricks wrote out the argument in detail: arxiv.org/abs/1107.2154, Prop. 6.10. See also Section 2.5 of the original Atiyah-Hirzebruch article.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the fact that we could use the Chern character to deduce the ranks on the $E_{\infty}$ page.