# Complex non stably trivial complex vector bundle with vanishing Chern classes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

There have been some discussions of a similar question, but I'd like an example of a non-trivial class in complex K-theory of an orientable manifold, for which all Chern classes vanish. This does not seem to be contained in these pages.

Links to similar discussion:

[Non-stably trivial bundle with trivial characteristic classes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112764/non-stably-trivial-bundle-with-trivial-charactertic-classes)

[Complex vector bundles with trivial Chern classes on k-tori](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35194/complex-vector-bundles-with-trivial-chern-classes-on-k-tori)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470464/when-characteristic-classes-determine-a-bundle

Comment: Analyzing an answer from one of the references, it looks like the following example should work: take the complexified tautological bundle $E$ over $\mathbb{R}P^7.$ Take $F = 8 E.$ Then the same calculations as those for the example on $\mathbb{R}P^6$ should prove that this is the right example. 

Are there any more examples? Constructed maybe from flat bundles?

Comment: $\mathbb R\mathbb P^7$ works, but still with $4E$; $8E$ is trivial. The only cohomological difference between $\mathbb R\mathbb P^6$ and $\mathbb R\mathbb P^7$ is a $\mathbb Z$ is degree $7$. But that's an odd degree, so it contributes neither to Chern classes nor to $K$-theory.